# jquery $.each breaks FormData appending

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm trying to create a drag'n'drop file uploader, and I've gotten to the point where the files are uploaded to the server. I'm using jQuery and the FormData object to formulate the request, and `$.ajax` to send it. I'm now running into an issue where if I iterate over my `files` array, nothing will be received over on the php side, but if I hard-append each file into the filesData `FormData` object, the php side will acknowledge receiving the files. Am I doing something wrong here?

```
    $("#upload-panel").on("drop", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      //files is now simply an array of file objects
      var files = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files; 

      var filesData = new FormData();

      // this doesn't work
      $.each(files, function(key, value) {
        filesData.append(key, files[key]);
        console.log(key);
        console.log(files[key]);
      });

      // this does
      filesData.append(0, files[0]);
      filesData.append(1, files[1]);
      // repeat for as many files.

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "file-processor.php",
        data: filesData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data, text, xhr) {
          console.log(data);
          console.log(text);
          console.log(xhr);
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, err) {
          $("#results").html += err;
        }
      });
    }
```

file-processor.php : `print_r($_FILES);`

`files` variable: 
[image: files]

Comment: and of course, I can't really debug `filesData` because `FormData` can't have their data viewed.

Answer (score 1):

you could try a regular `for loop` approach, which is just as easy and convenient. It would do exactly what your working code does.

```
  for (var i = 0, len = files.length; i < len; i++) 
    filesData.append(i, files[i]);
```

Comment: I replaced both the `//this doesn't work` and `//this does` sections with the snippet you posted and it yields an empty $_FILES array when POSTed.

Comment: hmmm. i don't get it. the only thing that seems even slightly off with your `$.each` is that you could use more dogmatic jquery fn args: `function(index, value)`. But that shouldn't affect the code.

Comment: It's quite strange. Here's what the `files` variable looks like when logged to the console: http://puu.sh/dNm0F/a50d720540.png

Comment: Actually, I just did a bit more troubleshooting and found that the wordpress zip file causes it to fail, whereas using other files does work using the for-loop.

Comment: nah. i meant server-side.

Comment: php.ini: `upload_max_filesize = 64M`

Comment: yeah, so that's not the issue; you've only got ~9M. hmm